# Cloning dom.Document object

Tags: java, xml, dom

My purpose is to read xml file into Dom object, edit the dom object, which involves removing some nodes.

After this is done i wish to restore the Dom to its original state without actually parsing the XML file.

Is there anyway i can clone the dom object i obtained after parsing the xml file for the first time. the idea is to avoid reading and parsing xml all the time, just keep a copy of original dom tree.

Comment: Possible dupe of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279154/how-can-i-clone-an-entire-document-using-the-java-dom

Answer (score 19):

You could use [importNode](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/org/w3c/dom/Document.html#importNode(org.w3c.dom.Node,%20boolean)) API on org.w3c.dom.Document:

```
Node copy = document.importNode(node, true);
```

---

**Full Example**

```
import java.io.File;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.w3c.dom.Document;
import org.w3c.dom.Node;

public class Demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();

        Document originalDocument = db.parse(new File("input.xml"));
        Node originalRoot = originalDocument.getDocumentElement();

        Document copiedDocument = db.newDocument();
        Node copiedRoot = copiedDocument.importNode(originalRoot, true);
        copiedDocument.appendChild(copiedRoot);

    }
}
```

Comment: Beware, this way of copying the document will remove processing instructions or comments within the file!

Comment: I believe this will remove any UserData that was appended to any nodes in the old document! It makes sense that it does that, but one has to be aware

Answer (score 9):

```
TransformerFactory tfactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
Transformer tx   = tfactory.newTransformer();
DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
DOMResult result = new DOMResult();
tx.transform(source,result);
return (Document)result.getNode();
```

This would be the Java 1.5 solution for making a copy of the DOM document. Take a look at [Transformer Factory](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/TransformerFactory.html) and [Transformer](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/javax/xml/transform/Transformer.html)

Comment: isEqualNode() doesn't return true if you copy in this way

Comment: This method keeps processing instructions and comments in the copy!

Answer (score 9):

you could clone a tree or only the node with DOMs cloneNode(boolean isDeepCopy) API.

```
Document originalDoc = parseDoc();
Document clonedDoc = originalDoc.cloneNode(true);
```

unfortunately, since cloneNode() on Document is (according to API) implementation specific, we have to go for a bullet-proof way, that is, create a new Document and import cloned node's from the original document:

```
...
Document clonedDoc = documentFactory.newDocument();
cloneDoc.appendChild(
  cloneDoc.importNode(originalDoc.getDocumentElement(), true)
);
```

note that none of operations are thread-safe, so either use them only locally, or Thread-Local or synchronize them.

Answer (score 1):

I would stick with the second suggestion with TransformerFactory.
With importNode you don't get a full copy of the document.
The header isn't copied.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<?aid style="50" type="snippet" readerVersion="6.0" featureSet="257" product="8.0(370)" ?>      
<?aid SnippetType="PageItem"?><Document DOMVersion="8.0" Self="d">
```

This would not return the above because this isn't copied. It's will be using what ever your new document contain.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
```